# How to make two Servlets share the same list of items

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

It's a simple CRUD web-app.

I have two Servlets.

One for listing(`MyProjectListServlet.java`) **all** the items on a page.

The other handles the updating(`MyPprojectEditorServlet.java`) of item information or adding **an item** to the list.

At the moment, both Servlets create and maintain their own list of same items. So, the list Servlet always shows its own list of unaltered items and update Servlet shows the updated item information(if you edit an item, otherwise it will show same information as the list servlet).

How do I make both Servlets(`MyProjectListServlet` and `MyPprojectEditorServlet`) to share the same one `itemRepo` list.

**MyProjectListServlet.java**:

```
package com.myproject;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.myproject.MyProjectRepository;

@WebServlet("/project/")
public class MyProjectListServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    private MyProjectRepositoryImpl itemsRepo = new MyProjectRepositoryImpl(); // creates brand new list of items

    public MyProjectListServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        request.setAttribute("items", itemsRepo.listItems());

        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/item-list.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

**MyPprojectEditorServlet.java**:

```
package com.myproject;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.myproject.myitem;
import com.myproject.myprojectRepository;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet("/project")
public class MyPprojectEditorServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    private MyProjectRepositoryImpl itemRepo = new MyProjectRepositoryImpl(); //creates its own list of items

    public MyProjectEditorServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String id = request.getParameter("id");

        if(id != null && !id.isEmpty()){
            MyItem item = itemRepo.lookupitemById(id);
            request.setAttribute("item", item);

        }

        request.setAttribute("items", itemRepo.listMyItems());

        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/item-form.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String str1 = request.getParameter("str1");
        String str2 = request.getParameter("str2");
        String str3 = request.getParameter("str3");
        String str4 = request.getParameter("str4");
        String str5 = request.getParameter("str5");

        String id = request.getParameter("id");
        if(id == null || id.isEmpty()){
            itemRepo.addItem(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
        }else{
            itemRepo.updateItem(id, str1, str2, str3, str4, str5);
        }
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/project/");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Save the list as an attribute of the HttpSession object (session scope).
2. Save the list as an attribute of the ServletContext object (application scope).

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a singleton/Application or Session scoped variable, or for a more scalable solution, you can store the data in something like JPA/Redis.

Comment: But I have the @ApplicationScoped annotation set for MyProjectRepositoryImpl which implements MyProjectRepository interface. Doesn't that make it application scoped like you said?

Comment: Yes, but if you have one servlet reading from it and another servlet possibly changing the values of the list at the same time, you need to make sure the list is thread-safe by adding a synchronized wrapper or other method.  With Redis however, you don't have to worry about thread-safety and as mentioned earlier, is much easier to scale.

Comment: This is actually a great use case CopyOnWriteArrayList as it's thread-safe and can be iterated in the view easily: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

The JPA (Java Persistence API, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) allows you to store your runtime objects in a database, making them accessible even if you restart your container or reload your servlet. To use the JPA, your classes need some annotations to define how an object should be stored in the database.

Once an object is saved, it can easily be accessed from other servlets again and modifications are also updated in the underlying database.